# Get available dates from DB in Rails?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

Currently I have a database table:

```
AVAILABLE_DATES
=======================
id | unix_day   | hour 
=======================
 1 | 1408579200 |  0      // 8/21/2014, 00:00:00
 2 | 1408579200 |  1      // 8/21/2014, 01:00:00
...
```

These are dates that are available for the user to select. On the "view" side of things, I have a jqueryui datepicker text field that allows the to select a date, it sends an ajax request for the hours that are available for the unix day (midnight of that day), and populates a dropdown next to the text field.

This kinda-sorta works, but is a little buggy and slow. Is there a better way to do this in rails? Essentially, a model called available_hours with a unix_day int and an hour int? Here is what I think it would / could do:

1. User selects day from a list of available days (ajax on calendar show and on change month?)
2. ajax for hours for that specific day
3. user selects an hour.
4. Repeat for a second available time field

Is there a rails-tastic gem that does this sort of thing?

EDIT:
10,000 ft view

I want users to be able to schedule a task with a start datetime and an end datetime. The task will be queued and run by a script that takes those times as input and outputs a summary csv. The available times represent files that have a particular timestamp.

Comment: Let's step back from the implementation details for a minute. From the ten-thousand-foot view, what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: It would be great if you could provide what you've tried so far and where in the code you are having trouble.